# PicoDVI and Adafruit GFX: code to extract the color palette from an 8-bit PNG

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-pico

I have Adafruit RP2040 Feather with DVI. I am going through examples and have an issue with following instructions to convert an 8 bit png image to the “RGB565” color format used by PicoDVI and Adafruit GFX.
At the bottom of https://learn.adafruit.com/picodvi-arduino-library-video-out-for-rp2040-boards?view=all there are some instructions how do the conversion. There is a python code that I cannot make it run successfully on Windows 10.
Here is the python code:

from PIL import Image, ImagePalette

with Image.open("dragon.png") as img:

```
pal = img.getpalette()
print("const uint16_t palette[] = {")
for i in range(len(pal) // 3):
    r = pal[i * 3 + 0] >> 3
    g = pal[i * 3 + 1] >> 2
    b = pal[i * 3 + 2] >> 3
    rgb = (r << 11) | (g << 5) | b;
    print("0x%04X, " % (rgb), end="")
print("};\n")

print("const uint8_t sprite[] = {")
for y in range(img.size[1]):
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        p = img.getpixel((x, y))
        print("0x%02X, " % (p), end="")
print("};\n")
```

When I run in (I am not a python developer) python2 I get:

PS C:\Users\PC\Downloads> c:\Python27\python convert.py File "convert.py", line 12 print("0x%04X, " % (rgb), end="") ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I run it with Python3 I get:

PS C:\Users\PC\Downloads> python3 convert.py const uint16_t palette[] = { Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\PC\Downloads\convert.py", line 7, in for i in range(len(pal) // 3): TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I've tried with different 8 bit png images.

Is there onother way to run it successfully in python? Is there a way to produce the same PicoDVi compatible mask the bits with ImageMagic, or C? How? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only acquire a palette if there is one. Most *.png pictures are true color images, like JPEG pictures. These have the color of each pixel saved as 8-bit R,G,B values, so there is no palette.
In this case, Image.getpalette() returns a 'None' object.
Your 'dragon.png' seems to be of this type. To convert it to a *.PNG with a palette you need a graphics tool that can convert it to a 256 color image. I used IrfanView.

You can check your image with this tool by pressing "i".
[image]

If it states '16,7 Million Colors' you don't have a palette, so you can reduce the color depth via "Image" ==> "Decrease Color Depth..." to 256 colors. Then save it to some PNG file and try again.

So your code should check the return value of "pal = img.getpalette()". Only if it's not None you can proceed.

Comment: Yes, after using as suggested IrfanView I was able to run the python code successfully. I appreciate it.